# jquery isotope select/option and unsorted list

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-isotope

I would like to combine SELECT/OPTION with UNORDERED LIST for jQuery-isotope combination filters. I got it to work with multiple SELECT/OPTION but cannot figure out how to combine both SELECT and UL.
Any help?

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/36/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this. I've updated your fiddle with UL.

This may help you. Hope this is what you wanted...

http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/39/

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats what i wanted to do.
Just one more thing: How do i pass a custom class to filtered items and only them?

Comment: I got it working to count the items shown and adding class to filtered items, but i cannot get the added class remove after all options are deselected. Can you help?
http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/45/

Comment: Please check this... http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/47/ Hope this will solve your prob.

Comment: Thank you. Yes my problem is solved. Only one more question. Where should i put a method to add: display: block to a div if all items are filtered out, nothing to show. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fgLUa/48/ Div with class="no-items" should get css display: block;